# R: Delete all values with less than 3 samples, count method without including NAs

Tags: r, csv, conditional-statements, na

I have a dataframe in a .csv sample file that looks like this.

```
NAME;   ID; REFERENCE_YEAR; VALUE
FORGOTTEN COL;  2282;   1987;   NA
FORGOTTEN COL;  2282;   1998;   NA
FORGOTTEN COL;  2282;   1999;   NA
FORGOTTEN COL;  2282;   2008;   NA
FORGOTTEN COL;  2282;   2010;   -48
FOX;    1536;   1894;   -140
FOX;    1536;   1934;   -480
FOX;    1536;   1955;   -280
FOX;    1536;   1956;   -1420
FOX;    1536;   1965;   180
FOX;    1536;   1967;   20
BURTON; 1606;   1996;   NA
BURTON; 1606;   1997;   NA
BURTON; 1606;   1998;   NA
BURTON; 1606;   1999;   NA
BURTON; 1606;   2007;   NA
BURTON; 1606;   2010;   0
BREWSTER;   1597;   1997;   -98
BREWSTER;   1597;   2005;   -8
AMARILLO;   233;    1936;   NA
AMARILLO;   233;    1937;   NA
AMARILLO;   233;    1938;   NA
BETA;   244;    2006;   NA
BETA;   244;    2007;   NA
BETA;   244;    2008;   NA
BETA;   244;    2009;   NA
```

You can also find the .csv file here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/test_count.csv

What I want to do in R with this: I'd like to filter out all VALUES that have less than three measurements (VALUES) based on the whole group of NAME and delete them from the dataframe. I am using the following code so far:

```
df <- read.csv("test_count.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)

z <- table(df$NAME)
df <- df[df$NAME %in% names(z)[z >3],]
```

The problem is that with this method, the NAs in VALUE get also counted which I don't want (e.g. in FORGOTTEN COL the only value that should be counted is -48, in BURTON it is 0) and the groups should therefore be deleted from the dataframe.

Is there a way to do this and exclude the NA values from the conditional statement? Exception: When there are only NA values like in AMARILLO they should also get deleted. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Changing your `table(df$NAME)` to `table(df$NAME[!is.na(df$VALUE)])` should be enough to accomplish that (by excluding NAs in the count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of non-NAs by ("by"!) NAME using `by()`:

```
foo <- with(df,by(VALUE,NAME,function(xx)sum(!is.na(xx))))
foo
```

These NAMEs have at least three non-NAs:

```
names(which(foo>=3))
```

So you want:

```
df[df$NAME %in% names(which(foo>=3)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`.

First, read the data using `read.csv2()`:

```
dat <- read.csv2("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/test_count.csv")
```

Then use two filters on the data:

- the first filter removes `NA` values
- the second removes all rows where the number of rows < 3

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by("NAME") %>% filter(!is.na(VALUE)) %>% filter(length(VALUE)>=3)

Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: NAME

  NAME   ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
1  FOX 1536           1894  -140
2  FOX 1536           1934  -480
3  FOX 1536           1955  -280
4  FOX 1536           1956 -1420
5  FOX 1536           1965   180
6  FOX 1536           1967    20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[with(df, ave(VALUE, NAME, FUN=function(x) sum(!is.na(x))))>=3,] 
 #   NAME   ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
 #6   FOX 1536           1894  -140
 #7   FOX 1536           1934  -480
 #8   FOX 1536           1955  -280
 #9   FOX 1536           1956 -1420
 #10  FOX 1536           1965   180
 #11  FOX 1536           1967    20
```

Or using your method

```
z <- table(!is.na(df$VALUE), df$NAME)[2,] ##change 
df[df$NAME %in% names(z)[z >= 3],]
#   NAME   ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE
#6   FOX 1536           1894  -140
#7   FOX 1536           1934  -480
#8   FOX 1536           1955  -280
#9   FOX 1536           1956 -1420
#10  FOX 1536           1965   180
#11  FOX 1536           1967    20
```